# ios - significant location change, and no Internet

Tags: ios, geofencing

I am using Significant Location Changes, and this is working fine. I then call a web api, and pass location data to this.

However, when I am not connected to the Internet, it cannot send the message.

How do I get around this?
I have tried putting a sleep into a recursive send routine.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];
        [self postURL :post :function];
    });
```

This works fine with the app in the foreground. It cannot send the message but will keep retrying, when the Internet is available it then sends the message, but when it is in the background it will call the postURL only once, the first time around the function.

How can I get around this? Or is there a better way to get background notifications when the Internet is lost, and reconnected.

Comment: maybe using a Reachability manager detecting when you have internet and then making your request, and keeping record of all your not sended messages until you can send it

Comment: I am not sure how that would work with the app in the background?

Comment: put the messages into a queue and try to post them one-by-one when you have connection again.

Comment: But how would you do that with the app in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this, switched to using `startUpdatingLocation` rather than using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.

This now seems to work.

I don't think `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` is suitable for sending location data back to a server.